# Confusion in formula for average memory access time

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I am looking at a memory hierarchy question from this [link](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~stevko/courses/cse490/spring11/files/midterm-sol.pdf)

The question asks to calculate AMAT (average memory access time)

[image]

The following is the formula given :

[image]

I also saw a presentation from stanford at this [link2](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee282h/handouts/Handout28.pdf)

The formula there is :

[image]

From searching on the web, my understanding is that AMAT at any level is :

```
 AMAT = hit time + local miss rate X miss penalty
```

So for the formula from stanford, it must be because :

```
 AMAT = hit time (L1) +  local miss rate (L1) X miss penalty (L1)
      = hit time (L1) +  local miss rate (L1) X [ hit time (L2) +  local miss rate (L2) X miss penalty (L2) ]
      = hit time (L1) +  local miss rate (L1) X hit time (L1) + **global miss rate (L2)** X miss penalty (L2)
```

(a) is the L2 miss rate in stanford's formula the global miss rate for L2 cache ?

(b) Why is the formula for the question from first link multiplying hit time with hit rate for L1 ?

(c) Why in the first formula, TLB miss penalty is added with TLB hit time (when in formulas for caches, miss rate is just multiplied with miss penalty) ?

(d) If the formula from first link is wrong, what is the right formula to calculate AMAT in case of such a question ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but anyway.

> (a) is the L2 miss rate in stanford's formula the global miss rate for
>   L2 cache ?

I'm not sure what you mean by "global", but the L2 miss rate in the formula refers to the whole L2 of the core issuing the request, taking into account all demand accesses to L2 from that core.

> (b) Why is the formula for the question from first link multiplying
>   hit time with hit rate for L1 ?

The confusion arises because the terms used in the formulas are not precisely defined. In the first formula, the hit time and miss penalty are *independent* quantities. That is, they do not overlap. I think it would have been better to call it "miss time" instead of "miss penalty."

But in the second formula, the miss penalty is an *additional* quantity over the hit time. So essentially the hit time is a base latency that is incurred 100% of the time, irrespective of whether it's a hit or a miss. The second formula could be rewritten as follows:

AMAT = 100% X hit time (L1) +  local miss rate (L1) X miss penalty (L1)

Therefore, both formulas are calculating AMAT in the same way (ignore TLB for now). It's just that the terms are defined differently.

> (c) Why in the first formula, TLB miss penalty is added with TLB hit
>   time (when in formulas for caches, miss rate is just multiplied with
>   miss penalty) ?

If you look at slide 17 of the [VM II](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu//~stevko/courses/cse490/spring11/files/vm2.pdf) lecture, you'll see that the instruction that issued the access is restarted upon a TLB miss (this means that all TLB misses are handled by the OS always, not the hardware). So on a TLB miss, the TLB hit latency is incurred again (in addition to the TLB miss penalty).

> (d) If the formula from first link is wrong, what is the right formula
>   to calculate AMAT in case of such a question ?

The formula is fine.